# Youtube API PlaylistItems does not return nextPageToken

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm using YouTube API documentation to get playlist items (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list).

But the API does not return the `nextPageToken` and `prevPageToken` properties. So I can't call the next playlist page.

The API call:

`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=RDMMfHI8X4OXluQ&key=...`

[image: youtube playlist call image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Also, please obey to SO guidelines: do not post source code and/or error messages embedded within images. Please post these as plain ([formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) text.

Comment: Please post the full API call that you've made, such that to be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Done! If you need anything else just let me know

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned the API key to be edited out.

Comment: I confirm the API behavior described above. It's quite surprising that the [`Playlists.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) API endpoint returns an [`itemCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists#contentDetails.itemCount) of value `10` for this playlist -- `RDMMfHI8X4OXluQ` --, while querying the `PlaylistItems.list` endpoint with `maxResults=50` does return 50 different video items.

Comment: Also interesting is that the YouTube's website itself says *This playlist type is unviewable* when querying it for this playlist: `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=RDMMfHI8X4OXluQ`.

Comment: I deem this to be a bug of this API; therefore, I recommend to file a bug report directly to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/) (mentioning the unexpected details described above).

Comment: Okay, I'm going to open a bug report as you suggested. Thanks man!